# Simultaneous eigenstate of commuting observables and their tensor product

Tags: entanglement, bell-experiment

So this is about something from Preskill's notes on Quantum Computation and Information, Chapter 4, page 3.

Imagine we have a maximally entangled state (Bell state). We can identify the Bell state by measuring the phase and parity bit with the **commuting** operators

$$\sigma_1^A \otimes \sigma_1^B \\
\sigma_3^A \otimes \sigma_3^B$$

Now they want to show that you cannot do this locally, so when Alice and Bob both are spacelike separated and can only do measurements on their own qubit A and B.

Following Preskill, they can start by measuring $\sigma_3^A$ and $ \sigma_3^B$ each on their own, and because this commutes with $\sigma_3^A \otimes \sigma_3^B$, this does not disturb the parity bit. So they prepared a simultaneous eigenstate of $\sigma_3^A$ and $ \sigma_3^B$. These eigenstates do not commute with $ \sigma_1^A \otimes \sigma_1^B$ so they disturbed the phase bit so they cannot measure it. Conclusion: they cannot read the information that is in the entanglement.

But my real question now is: why do the first two observables $ \sigma_1^A \otimes \sigma_1^B$ and $
\sigma_3^A \otimes \sigma_3^B$ commute, when $\sigma_3^A$ and $ \sigma_3^B$ will not commute with $ \sigma_1^A \otimes \sigma_1^B$. Because in my opinion, we can write the effect of the measurement of Alice and Bob on the state as;

$$\sigma_3^A \otimes I^B \\
I^A \otimes \sigma_3^B$$

which, when measured after each other will have the effect on $|\psi\rangle$:

$$(\sigma_3^A \otimes I^B)
(I^A \otimes \sigma_3^B) |\psi\rangle = \sigma_3^A \otimes \sigma_3^B |\psi\rangle$$

which is the original measurement that can be done when both qubits are at the same place? So what is the difference, why is this not the same eigenstate? I must be missing something, but I don't see where I make an error. Can someone please explain.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question from where you say "...we can write the effect of the measurement of Alice and Bob on the state as...". Measurement cannot be represented by unitary transformations like $\sigma_3^A \otimes I^B$ or $I^A \otimes \sigma_3^B$.

Comment: Uh, okay, trying really hard here but, on a one qubit state you apply $\sigma_3$ to measure the spin on the z-axis? So if you would try to measure the spin on the z-axis of spin A of a two qubit system, I would assume you use $\sigma_3^A \otimes I^B$? How do you mean that measurement cannot be represented by unitary transformations? Okay, maybe I get that, but what does "apply $\sigma$" mean then if we don't let the operators work on our state? My question remains that $\sigma_3^A \otimes I^B$ and $ I^A \otimes \sigma_3^B $ "applied" consecutively comes down to $\sigma_3^A \otimes \sigma_3^B$

Comment: So I don't really get the difference between applying $\sigma_3^A \otimes I^B$ and $ I^A \otimes \sigma_3^B $ and $\sigma_3^A \otimes \sigma_3^B$ then? So maybe you can help me understand the difference? What does the measurement do then? Or how do you depict it, is it because the post measurement state is completely different? Or what happens?

Comment: Preskill probably means that you're carrying out the measurements in the eigenbases of the operators. Measurements themselves cannot be represented as operators.

Comment: Projective measurements are represented as operators though right? You can create projection operators? Or what am I missing here... I seem to think I don't really get what a measurement is, if given an "operator". If you have the commuting observable $\sigma_A \otimes \sigma_B$, to observe this, you have to do a measurement, right?

Comment: A POVM (general measurement) is a set of operators, right? So how is a measurement not an operator?

Comment: Playing loose with terminology will only confuse you. POVM is a **measure** (in the measure theoretic sense); it's not an operator. Sure you can describe it as a **set** of positive semidefinite operators, but it's *not* an operator in itself.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I am indeed not the best in rigorous terminology and do not master quantum information that well as you may have noticed. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Regarding your previous comment: you can only write down the projection operator corresponding to a measurement *after* you know the outcome of the measurement. So it doesn't really make sense to call measurement an operator. Anyway, I'll try to write an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Measuring an **observable** does *not* mean applying the [observable operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#Measurable_quantities_(%22observables%22)_as_operators) to a quantum state but rather measuring the state in the eigenbasis of the operator. A measurement will basically produce an eigenvalue of that observable operator and the system will collapse to a subspace corresponding to all states having that eigenvalue. For example, if you're measuring in the $\sigma_1$ basis, then you'll get either $+1$ corresponding to the eigenstate $|+\rangle$ or $-1$ corresponding to the eigenstate $|-\rangle$. Similarly, if you measure in the $\sigma_3$ basis then you'll either get $+1$ corresponding to the eigenstate $|0\rangle$ or $-1$ corresponding to the eigenstate $|1\rangle$.
2. The fact that $\sigma_3^A$ and $\sigma_3^B$ do not commute with $\sigma_1^A\otimes \sigma_1^B$ is a purely mathematical artefact and it's easy to prove along [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2804083/568976) lines. There's  also a technical mistake in your sentence: "These **eigenstates do not commute** with $\sigma_1^A\otimes \sigma_1^B$ so they disturbed the phase bit so they cannot measure it."; it's meaningless to say that a state doesn't commute with an operator — commutators are only defined for operators.